# CSS Links wont change colour

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink

I am trying to change color of a link but I am having no luck.

```
<section class="sectionFooter">
    <font class="copyrightText">&copy; 2015</font><br>
    <font class="copyrightText"></font><br>
    <font class="footer"><a href="./tandc.php">Terms and Conditions</a> - <a href="./privacypolicy.php">Privacy Policy</a></font><br> 
</section>
```

I have tried to style it with a stylesheet using the following.

```
.sectionFooter a, .sectionFooter a:link, .sectionFooter a:visited, .sectionFooter a:active, .sectionFooter a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

and

```
.footer a, .footer a:link, .footer a:visited, .footer a:active, .footer a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I am sure I am missing something simple, Everything else works great on the page.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `font` tag is depreciated.

Comment: Hi Josh, I put that in there to test actually, I was using <span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey first are you creating html in doctype html that is html5 so here is one link that says font tag is deprecated 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

So instead of using font tag use a span tag if you want inline your code is perfectly fine

Here the js fiddle

.sectionFooter a { `color: #000;` }

http://jsfiddle.net/kp1zsncc/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using inline CSS, Looked to see if anything was overriding it in the CSS file and nothing. Not sure what the actual issue was.

Answer (score 0):

try this.,

```
<section class="sectionFooter">
    <font class="copyrightText">&copy; 2015</font><br>
    <font class="copyrightText"></font><br>
    <font class="footer"><a href="./tandc.php">Terms and Conditions</a> - <a href="./privacypolicy.php">Privacy Policy</a></font><br> 
</section>

.sectionFooter a, .sectionFooter a:link, .sectionFooter a:visited, .sectionFooter a:active, .sectionFooter a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.footer a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
 .footer a:link, .footer a:visited, .footer a:active, .footer a:hover {
   color:red;
}
    section {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }/* added for your reference */
```